# Getting a particular detail from XML file in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am working on a CRM app in android, in which, I am showing details of all contacts in a list view. Now, my requirement is when I click on a particular item in the list, it should only  display the details about selected contact, such as, name, address, email, etc.. The data is coming from XML file, which I am parsing using SAX Parser. How can I query a XML to get selected data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the `ListView` using `Adapter` right? Now you can get the item at the selected view inside the `ListView` and pass this item to an `Activity`.

E.g. inside your `Adatper` class implement the `onItemClickListener`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long l) {
    // Remembers the selected Index
    Data item =getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailedActivity.class);
    intent.put("object",item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note: the item "Data" class should implement the `Parsable` interface so it can be passed to the `Activity` in your `DetailedActivity` `onCreate` method get that object and update the `UI` based on its Values.